# Can changes be conflictless overwritten when using git merge with recursive strategy?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I am managing the source code of a project in my company with Git (GitLab) to be precise. Two developers work on the project, create a branch for every task then create a merge request. I mostly merge these directly via the UI which should be the same as doing this in the command line:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff 1224-cool-feature-branch
```

From time to time I have seen small features or parts of pages disappear.

Consider the following case

- Dev A branches from master at ab12 -> new branchname `FeatureA`
- Dev B branches from master at ab12 -> new branchname `FeatureB`
- Dev A changes `foobar.txt` and commits to `FeatureA`
- FeatureA is merged into master using `merge --no-ff` using the default recursive strategy
- Dev B changes `foobar.txt` and commits to Feature B
- FeatureB is merged into master using `merge --no-ff` using the default recursive strategy without conflict

***Is it possible that changes to `foobar.txt` from `FeatureA`have been overwritten without creating a conflict?***

Comment: When you merge feature to master, the code of master will be changed because commits of feature are introduced to master. This is what `merge` does by default, working as designed.

Comment: If the question is: If neither branch changed some file, will a merge change it? Then the answer is no, unless someone manually, as part of that merge, changes that file.

Comment: It can be more constructive if you focus on one specific feature you think have disappeared and find out the reason for it. You can check for each commit content of the file by command `git show <commit>:<path>`

Comment: I rephrased my question completely with an example of the workflow that leads to the observed behaviour.
@max630 I am looking for features but have trouble finding one I am sure was caused by this. If I do I will use `git log` and `git show` to find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is "no". The file is merged using the conventional [3 way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(version_control)#Three-way_merge) which should apply change if they are distant enough from each other or report a conflict, there is no other option.

There could be some issues with this approach, see for example http://r6.ca/blog/20110416T204742Z.html , but I cannot imagine how any corner case would result in silent edit reversal.