# git commited code lines disappear

Tags: git, git-merge

At work we have begun to notice some weird git behavior that I am at a loss to explain. Someone will make a commit, and later (usually after a merge), some of the lines of code in the commit will be undone. This isn't the whole commit, and can affect just part of a file. It also seems to happen after a normal successful merge (i.e. there was not a conflict that was resolved poorly).

Sometimes this is noticeable, like when part of a file changes, other times it can be more subtle. It does not look deliberate, and it does not appear that the people affected use things like rebase, commit amend, revert, etc. that could provide a simple explanation. Naturally the code that disappears is always older code that was not modified in the newer commits.

Is there any other way that parts of previous commits could be overridden by git during a conflictless merge?

Comment: Have you browsed the git log to figure out how and when the lines disappear? Can you post the two parent commits and merged commit where you notice the disappearing text?

Comment: find an example with something relatively unique in one of these missing lines and use `git log -Gphrase` for a list of all commits that either added or removed a line with that phrase in it. Should narrow down the search for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can changes be conflictless overwritten when using git merge with recursive strategy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453017/can-changes-be-conflictless-overwritten-when-using-git-merge-with-recursive-stra)

Comment: Actually, to clarify the question, is the code disappearing in the merged commit, but retained in the original commit, or do you see code disappearing from the original commit?

Comment: @LightBender the original commit is fine, it is just the merged commit that is affected.

Comment: @T.Propst Just checking, if that was the case some deliberate manipulation is going on (or something is seriously broken) because git commits cannot be altered (only replaced). Try scanning the git log as suggested in my previous comment, it has most likely been altered in an intermittent commit or on the other branch. If you can find it, let me know and I'll write up the method as a proper answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sometimes team members will `squash` their commits when they are ready to merge. Over the course of development, it might be helpful to make many commits and have a pretty active git history.

When it comes time to merge your branch into master (and of course you've had your PR reviewed by your peers :wink:) you might opt to squash your commits into one, this will make the history more manageable for a large team.

You can do that by checking your git log:

```
git log
```

Then selecting the commits you want to combine into one:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Per the docs your `EDITOR` will be loaded with each commit, and it's message, follow the prompt in the editor:

```
pick 01d1124 Adding license
pick 6340aaa Moving license into its own file
pick ebfd367 Jekyll has become self-aware.
pick 30e0ccb Changed the tagline in the binary, too.

# Rebase 60709da..30e0ccb onto 60709da
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

> Some teams follow [this particular workflow](http://endoflineblog.com/gitflow-considered-harmful) and prefer their teammates do this, there are arguments against this.

Comment: Why would I get down voted for that answer, that is a perfectly valid thing that may happen.